# c# newtonsoft json.net populate json object inside object resulting null value

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have json like this:

```
{"ok":true,"user_id":1,"name":"ceil bleu","name_f":"ceil","name_l":"bleu","email":"xxxx@email.com","login":"ceilbleu","subscriptions":{"1":"2037-12-31","4":"2037-12-31","5":"2037-12-31","6":"2037-12-31"},"categories":[],"groups":[],"resources":["<a href=\"http:\/\/aa.com\/member\/signup\" class=\"am-resource-link\" id=\"resource-link-link-7\">Beli\/Perpanjang Keanggotaan<\/a>","<a href=\"http:\/\/aa.com\/member\/profile\" class=\"am-resource-link\" id=\"resource-link-link-15\">Unsubscribe<\/a>"]}
```

and a class called LoginDetail.cs represents json above:

```
public class LoginDetail
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_f { get; set; }
    public string name_l { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public Subscriptions subscriptions { get; set; }
    public object[] categories { get; set; }
    public object[] groups { get; set; }
    public string[] resources { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriptions
{
    public string _1 { get; set; }
    public string _4 { get; set; }
    public string _5 { get; set; }
    public string _6 { get; set; }
}
```

Then on main class I populate the json like this:

```
LoginDetail loginDetail = new LoginDetail();

            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, loginDetail);
 var a = loginDetail.subscriptions._6;

                Console.WriteLine("subs 6:" + a);
```

But `var a` is resulting a null value.

How do I get subscriptions data?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including the `json` string variable.

Comment: Tried your code and it looks to be working for me. (@mjwills, you could either cut off the resources section and paste this as a string variable or just load it from file)

Comment: @JleruOHep There is a strong possibility that it isn't working due to the way that the OP is loading the JSON. Hence why I am asking for a [mcve].

Comment: decorate `Subscriptions` properties with ` @JsonProperty("1")` for `_1` and then use `JsonConvet.Deserialize<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class structure as below

```
public class LoginDetail
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_f { get; set; }
    public string name_l { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public Subscriptions subscriptions { get; set; }
    public object[] categories { get; set; }
    public object[] groups { get; set; }
    public string[] resources { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriptions
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string _1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4")]
    public string _4 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5")]
    public string _5 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("6")]
    public string _6 { get; set; }
}
```

And then I replaced double quotes with single quotes in the JSON string (only for testing purpose) and then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` to get login detail

```
var json = 
        @"{'ok':true,'user_id':1,'name':'ceil bleu','name_f':'ceil','name_l':'bleu','email':'xxxx@email.com','login':'ceilbleu','subscriptions':  {'1':'2037-12-31','4':'2037-12-31','5':'2037-12-31','6':'2037-12-31'} ,'categories':[],'groups':[],'resources':['<a href=\'http://aa.com/member/signup\' class=\'am-resource-link\' id=\'resource-link-link-7\'>Beli\/Perpanjang Keanggotaan<\/a>','<a href=\'http:\/\/aa.com\/member\/profile\' class=\'am-resource-link\' id=\'resource-link-link-15\'>Unsubscribe<\/a>']}";
var loginDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginDetail>(json);
```